# Append data after root element without loading the whole XML file into memory

Tags: java, xml

I have  to output an  XML file which can contain use amount of data, I am using DOM parser to write XML file. It is also possible to append data to an existing XML file.

My requirement is add data to the root element.

Is it possible to append data without reading the entire XML document (Not to load XML into  memory)?

*Example Data:*

Current XML file:

```
<employees>
     <employee>
         <name>jon</name>
         <age> 22</age>
         <address> address1 </address>
     </employee>
</employees>
```

Required file:

```
 <employees>
     <employee>
         <name>jon</name>
         <age> 22</age>
         <address> address1 </address>
     </employee>

      <employee>
         <name>jon1</name>
         <age> 24</age>
         <address> address2 </address>
     </employee>
</employees>
```

Comment: In any case - XML FILE will be loaded into the memory.

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard if you don't want to load entire XML into memory.

You can achieve this by manipulating raw String (substring, etc.) - but I don't recommend this.

<del>Or you can try using SAX reader http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html which enables you to manipulate XMLs "on the go".</del> (I'm sorry, although you can use SAX parsers to process XML without reading its whole content, you cannot edit with it)

**EDIT:**
On second though you can **copy** existing XML using SAX parser, and by adding event listener to e.g. root you can add a child. It might be good solution if your concern is memory (big xml file).

Comment: If I am not wrong XMLReader is used to read an XML document can I use this class to edit or add new element to a XML

Answer (score -1):

You could use [DOM4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) for doing that.